# If file exists delete another file

Tags: c#, file, if-statement, exists, delete-file

I need to delete file when other file exists.

```
Directory.GetFiles(dirName)
     .Select(f => new FileInfo(f))
     .Where(f => f.exists)
     .ToList()
     .ForEach(f => f.Delete());
```

This is working code to automatically delete file, but **I need to modify it to delete other file in other directory.**

File in directory2 has slightly different name.
Filename in directory1 = MyFileName()
but filename in directory2 = MyFileName

E.g. In **"C://folder123"** exists file **"File123()"**
     and I need to detect it and delete file in **"C://My documents/folder456"** named **"File123"**

//edit

I've written something and I think it should work but I must figure out problem with applicationpool to test it:

```
string path = "directory2";
        Directory.GetFiles("directory1")
        .Where(f => f.Contains("()") == true)
        .Select(f => f.TrimEnd(')', '('))
        .ToList();
        File.Delete(path);
```

Comment: Best way is to create mapping datastructure in database or somewhere else and perform same operation.

Comment: I´ve improved the question.

Answer (score 0):

What about this solution?

```
string sourcePath = "c:\\folder123\file123()";
string secondPath = "c:\\documents\\folder456";

if(File.Exists(sourcePath))
{
    FileInfo sInfo = new FileInfo(sourcePath);
    string dFilePath = Path.Combine(secondPath, sInfo.Name.Replace("()",""));
    if(File.Exists(dFilePath))
        File.Delete(dFilePath);
}
```

Im writing it on my iPad, so I hope it is right. Maybe the string "()" require escape chars.

Comment: Thank you for answer!

I´ve wrote something similar and I think it should work but I must figure out problem with applicationpool to test it. I am newbie so I haven´t set my computer properly yet and some applications just don´t work because they don´t have fully access to some folders etc.
    
    string path = "directory2";
            Directory.GetFiles("directory1")
            .Where(f => f.Contains("()") == true)
            .Select(f => f.TrimEnd(')', '('))
            .ToList();
            File.Delete(path);    
    

PS. Potěší vidět první odpověď od zrovna Čecha :)